# Automating text entry using gesture keyboard in Android

Tags: keyboard, gesture

I am new to the android development platform and working on a project to write some test comparing some of the different gesture keyboard implantations (android 4.2 built in, swipe and swift key).
I am using eclipe for my IDE and relying primarily on the emulator for testing. I am using the 4.2 gesture keyboard from here (http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1964663).

What I would like to be able to do (starting with android 4.2 built keyboard).

1. Pass a string in, for example “hello” and then have that string entered using the gesture keyboard.
2. Get the words shown in the Candidates View box.
3. Compare the words to an expected word and return pass/fail depending on if the words returned from Candidates View were what I expected.
4. Store passed in word and returned suggestions in a log file for analysis.
   Ideally I would like able to use API’s only for this and not reply on UI but I am not sure if this is possible.

Some possible solution I am looking at.

Use TouchUtils class (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/TouchUtils.html) to draw shapes between keys. However, I am not sure how I can specific x and y coordinates on device to map to specific keys. Also I don’t see any methods in this class that would let me draw a custom based shape.

Also I see the sendKeys(String keysSequence) however this looks like it just presses key and would not exercise to gesture keyboard stuff.

So I am curious how all you advance android developers would approach/solve this problem and if there is already any resources/API’s out there that can help.

Thanks
Pete

Answer (score 0):

You can try MonkeyRunner tool
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html

Or you can try "Programmatically Injecting Events on Android" in the below two blog posts (part 1 and part 2)

http://www.pocketmagic.net/2012/04/injecting-events-programatically-on-android/#.UckpTZwlubq

http://www.pocketmagic.net/2013/01/programmatically-injecting-events-on-android-part-2/#.UckpSZwlubp